# selectively avoid writing sensitive data to the log in ansible (without using nolog)

Tags: powershell, ansible, dsc

I am using a combination of DSC and Ansible.  With anything less than a trivial resource, PSCredentials is often required, these are split into two lines like this example:

```
PsDscRunAsCredential_username: '{{ansible_user}}'
PsDscRunAsCredentual_password: '{{ansible_password}}'
```

To avoid writing sensitive info to the Ansible log (e.g. when run in verbose mode, or if it errors), the suggestion is to use the 'nolog' flag.

Unfortunately, this suppresses all information - so if there is an error, you simply get 'CENSORED' returned.

I'm hoping it is possible to amend win_dsc to be a little smarter about this, and was wondering if anyone could point to a similar example in another module that I could learn/borrow from, assuming this is a common requirement?

I would basically like to avoid logging data if the parameter ends with "_password".

Comment: I think that's what the Ansible vault is for. You could use an encrypted secret:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html?highlight=encrypted#use-encrypt-string-to-create-encrypted-variables-to-embed-in-yaml

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't think that will help here; vaulted secrets expand to plain old variables during the play as long as you provided the correct secret to decrypt them, so all the tasks and such have no idea they're dealing with a vaulted variable, and the rest of the ansible engine treats them the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think you can alter this at the module level. In theory, a module knows which things it asks for should be secret (like a password, or API key), but really the heart of the problem lies outside of the task.

In verbose mode and in logs, ansible will show the invocation of a module, including secrets. `no_log` is the only solution they give, and given that `no_log` lives outside the module, there's nothing you could do in the module differently anyway.

Even if you could, the logging and verbose output are on the ansible engine side of things, so it's on them to fix and [based on this issue it doesn't look like there's any interest in doing more than providing `no_log`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18184).

[I have an answer on another question that goes into how you can more easily directly test a DSC invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545334/3905079); it's focused on the unique challenges of debugging DSC, and can get you to the point where you're stepping through code so it should be somewhat helpful in troubleshooting.